# Charles just shows unknown packages

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, reverse-proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to analyse my Iphone traffic, I enabled the SSL proxy and set everything. The problem is.. I just got these unknown packs, I can't see anything, any clue??

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Ensure you have trust settings enabled on your device.

1. Select 'Settings' > 'General' > 'About' > 'Certificate Trust Settings'
2. Enable the Charles Proxy certificate

[Enable certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h0Kq.png)

Comment: What is it on android?

Comment: What for ios Simulator?

Comment: @RamPrasadBismil See my answer below.

Comment: @A.Trejo See my answer below.

Comment: 2 steps are needed after going to https://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl using the ios device : 1) Install the downloaded profile (Settings root), then 2) Trust the certificate (Settings>General>About>Certificate Trust Settings)

Comment: what is it for windows or mac?

Answer (score 6):

- To install Charles root certificate on an Android emulator

  1. Launch Charles from your Mac
  2. Go to the Android settings on the emulator
  3. Select Wifi
  4. Select AndroidWifi network
  5. Select the pencil icon in the upper-right-hand corner.
  6. Select the "Advanced Options" accordion
  7. Enable manual proxy settings (just like a physical device)
  8. Navigate to chls.pro/ssl in the emulator's browser and install the root certificate (Keep it set to VPN)
  9. Confirm the prompt from Charles that an external device is attempting to proxy using Charles
  10. Charles is now configured.
- To install Charles root certificate on an iOS simulator

  1. Launch Charles from your Mac
  2. Select Help > SSL Proxying > Save Charles Root Certificate
  3. Drag & drop the saved certificate into an open simulator
  4. In the simulator open Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings
  5. Ensure the certificate is trusted.
  6. Restart the simulator.
  7. Charles is now configured.

Answer (score -2):

I got it, you just have to move the CA to the right path; it's not to the default path, you have to move to the "Trusted Folder" when installed.

Comment: What is CA? Please explain your answer. I am getting the same problem.

Comment: I believe he means a [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)